# Arrays class is not identified

Tags: java

I have JDK8 installed and JRE is also pointing to JRE 8 in my project. But somehow the below code is not compiling.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char[] chars = new char[] { '\u0097' };
        String str = new String(chars);
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
    }
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[Please see my JRE system library, expanded on the left hand side ,it has rt.jar
][2]

Comment: how do you get it if you don't import it

Comment: I tried it. I am having experience in java. But I am trying on new machine. I tried Arrays. nothings shows up.

Comment: If you expand `JRE System Library [jdk1.8.0_65]` on the left, then expand `rt.jar`, `java`, and `util`, do you see `Arrays.class`?

Comment: There is a bulb you can click on. What does it propose?

Comment: Ya, I could see Arrays.class under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\rt.zip\java\util

Comment: Try a manual clean and rebuild.  Maybe eclipse hasn't recompiled since you added the import statement?

Comment: build automatically is enabled on my eclipse and moreover I did the clean up manually but still not luck!

Comment: I didn't ask if you could see it in the file system, I asked if you could see it under `JRE System Library` on the left.

Comment: The bulb as usually says create Arrays class !!

Comment: May I know why people downgraded my question?

Comment: You got a lot of drive-by down-votes on the first iteration of your question before you cleaned it up.  Most of those people were too impatient/lazy to stick around and un-down-vote after the edits.

Comment: ok thanks  azurefrog for the explanation. as it is my first post ,it took a bit while to post it correctly. user please upgrade else my account will be closed I think

Comment: @Andreas , If expand JRE System Library, I don't see nothing. why?

Comment: **THAT** is your problem, and it's because the JDK is not correctly registered with your workspace (did you upgrade Java?). Go to `Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Installed JREs`, then Remove and re-Add JRE Definition named `jdk1.8.0_65`, making sure you see the `rt.jar` in the add dialog after you've selected the home directory.

Comment: Never mind, @Andreas beat me to it.  I'm out of votes, so pretend I upvoted your comment Andreas... ;-)

Comment: @azurefrog I'm good at pretending, so many thanks!!! *<bows>*

Comment: @Andreas, I have re moved JRE and added it again but still the error is not resolved. please see last screen shot in my post

Comment: Can you expand `rt.jar` and see `Arrays.class`? Did you do a clean build?

Comment: @Andreas, yes I did.

Comment: Finally, I uninstalled jdk 8 and installed jdk7 and re opened my eclipse and no errors. i dont know why. did any one tried eclipse latest (helios) on win 10 with Java 8?

Comment: Helios (3.6) is from June 23, 2010, and is far from the latest, and it doesn't support Java 8. Luna (4.4) from June 25, 2014 is the first version with integrated Java 8 support. Latest version is Mars (4.5) from June 24, 2015. *(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is issue with eclipse version.

Answer from user @Andreas

Helios (3.6) is from June 23, 2010, and is far from the latest, and it doesn't support Java 8. Luna (4.4) from June 25, 2014 is the first version with integrated Java 8 support. Latest version is Mars (4.5) from June 24, 2015.

Thanks to @Andreas and all who responded to me